# Move GNOME file dialog buttons

Tags: gnome, gui, gtk3

I recently upgraded to 18.04 and something that annoys me slightly is that the "Cancel" and "Open"/"Select" buttons are on the top bar now. Is there any way I can move them to the bottom, like in Unity?

[image]

For comparison:

[image]

Comment: Yeah one stupid decision :( still no way to change this.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This solution worked for me. Enter this line in the terminal.

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.xsettings overrides "{'Gtk/DialogsUseHeader':<0>}"
```

And buttons are back on the bottom of the dialog.

Comment: This worked for me for just about everything, except the Screenshots app. Any idea what setting to change for that?

Comment: If somebody is trying to do it in XFCE, then the right command is `xfconf-query -c xsettings -p /Gtk/DialogsUseHeader -s false`

Answer (score 0):

Just recently ran into this on a fresh install of Xubuntu 22.04.1 and found this solution: Open "XFCE Settings" > "Xfconf Settings Editor" > "xsettings" and click the "+ Add" button. In the dialog enter "/Gtk/DialogsUseHeader" as a boolean and set it to false.
Looks to be the same as others but in GUI form. Hope this helps.
Credit for the solution here: https://hardforum.com/threads/move-dialog-buttons-in-nautilus-back-to-the-bottom-of-the-dialog.2006565/post-1044911008