# How to change the position of save and cancel buttons (for example, when you download a file from web)?

Tags: gnome, 18.04, gui

This question is the same as [Move GNOME file dialog buttons](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1031665/move-gnome-file-dialog-buttons). However,the answer given there didn't work for me. The answer was

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.xsettings overrides "{'Gtk/DialogsUseHeader':<0>}"
```

Typing the above, gave me the following error.

```
GLib-GIO-Message: 11:59:17.132: Using the 'memory' GSettings backend.  Your settings will not be saved or shared with other applications.
```

Kindly, help me in solving this. I have also tried issuing the above command in sudo mode but without success.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/558446/my-dconf-gsettings-installation-is-broken-how-can-i-fix-it-without-ubuntu-reins has several methods

Comment: @Rinzwind Thanks. I have seen this but I haven't tried the solution as mine was a fresh installation. However, I will try it and update here. Are you aware of any problems with the procedure mentioned in the solution?